# Can iterator points to specific position instead of value in STL set?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

```
set<int> st;
set<int>::iterator it;

for(int i=10; i<20;i++)
    st.insert(i);

it = st.begin();
advance(it, 4); // it points to the 5th element which is 14

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    st.insert(i);

// At this point where does it points to? The 5th element which is 4, 
// or the old element having value 14?
```

Say I have a C++ STL `set` of `int`, then I move the iterator to somewhere middle (the 5th element in the example), then I insert some more elements which the container may change the position of the elements. After that, where does the iterator points to?

If it is pointing to the old value instead of the position I specified, **is there any method (not necessary using iterator) to keep getting the 5 th element even after the element has changed (without calling advance() again)?** Thanks.

---

To clarify, I have tested by the following code:

```
st.insert(4);
it = st.begin();
st.insert(3);
st.insert(2);
cout << *it << endl;
```

It was printing 4, while in my situation I want to always access a element at specific position, say `st.begin()+3` (if exist), thus the question

Comment: What happened when you checked?

Comment: Sets don't acutally have "positions," which is probably related to how they are implemented. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @juanchopanza It seems always pointing to the old value

Comment: @JohnPerry Yes, I know it is not for random access. But in my case I have to access the element at specified "position" using STL set...

Comment: @juanchopanza I think my question is that "If it is pointing to the old value, then is there anyway to achieve the behavior I desire", am I missing something?

Comment: @shole Well, the whole point of not having random access is that you can't access a specific position. If you care about specific position you simply can't use a set because it could be, for instance, rebalanced at any time.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because I am not sure am I missing anything in my own test so I ask for a confirmation of that as well, my whole question is more about the bold text. Sorry if that confuses you

Comment: @JohnPerry Thanks, your comments are useful, they at least helped me to explain to my colleague why the requirement may be not reasonable

Comment: @shole Oh, is this one of those Dilbert moments? :-)

Comment: @JohnPerry Yea, and he "proposed" to consult other experts on some famous site like SO, so I did it, and your comments will slap his face :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going on the question in bold,

> **is there any method (not necessary using iterator) to keep getting the 5 th element even after the element has changed (without calling advance() again)?**

***No***, there is no way to always access a specific position. At least one compiler implements sets as trees. Trees are often rebalanced in order to maintain efficiency of search, insert, etc. The penalty is that you can't count on any element to remain in any particular position after an insert.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` is an associative container, so position of its elements have no meaning. Your iterator is pointing to the same element, because `std::set::insert` is not invalidating iterators. There is no guarantee, that this will be 5th element although. If you need an container with the fixed positions, use `std::vector` or `std::list` instead.

Comment: Thanks..I was using std:list actually, but in my case the streaming input needs to keep sorted, so I use std:multiset  instead... (OP uses set for simplicity)

Comment: You could sort your list using `std::sort` instead.

Comment: That would be too slow, as it is not acceptable to call sort() every time a new integer comes...

Comment: @shole You could perform a binary search on a vector when you insert an element. That both maintains it sorted and lets you move quickly.

Comment: Well its difficult to tell without knowing your application specifics. Perhaps you could buffer a data for some time and then sort it, or sort before outputting to the algorithm, that is requiring sorting.

Answer (score 1):

It points to the same element. Not necessarily the same position in the set as the set is ordered. Read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/